# Pandas - iterate over rows in specific column and find empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataframe with more than 50 000 rows.

input :
[image]

I am trying to iterate over rows until the first empty cell and then copy the value of the id only if *par* exists. Unfortunately, this does not work.

In other words, what I aim to do is replace *par* with the value of the column1 (*id_1, id_2, id_3*) to the **column3** respectively.
The output would be something like :

[image]

Comment: `np.where(df['Column3'] == 'par', df['Column1'], np.nan)`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris it won't help, np.where can't be used this way. Look at the values in Column1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to fillup each group of same `id` with the `id` values in each row in `Column1`.  Then change `Column3` values with `par` to these `id` values in the same row by using [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), as follows:

```
Col1_id = df['Column1'].where(df['Column1'].str.startswith('id_')).ffill()

df['Column3'] = df['Column3'].mask(df['Column3'] == 'par', Col1_id)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Column1 Column2 Column3
0     id_1     NaN     NaN
1    n="1"   whose    id_1
2    n="2"  theirs    id_1
3    n="3"      am    id_1
4      NaN     NaN     NaN
5     id_2     NaN     NaN
6    n="4"      in    id_2
7    n="5"     out    id_2
8      NaN     NaN     NaN
9     id_3     NaN     NaN
10   n="6"      in    id_3
11   n="7"     out    id_3
```

Comment: @Artemis  Is it possible there will be values other than `par` and `NaN` in Column3 ?  If yes, take caution that Arkadiusz's solution may make those value `NaN` while my solution should works well with this.

Comment: I added a comment to my answer with explanation what can be done in such situation. From the post with question we can conclude there are 'par' and 'nan' in column3. If there is something more - it's a user's decision then. He can decide if it's better to put 'nan' there or leave existing value.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the DataFrame on empty rows using [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).
2. If "par" is in Column3, replace all "par" in Column3 with the first non-null value from "Column 1" using `str.replace`
3. Append the modified "chunk" to the output.

##### Solution:

```
import numpy as np

output = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in np.split(df, df[df.isnull().all(1)].index):
    if "par" in chunk["Column3"].tolist():
        chunk["Column3"] = chunk["Column3"].str.replace("par", chunk["Column1"].dropna().iat[0])
    output = output.append(chunk)

>>> output
   Column1 Column2 Column3
0     id_1    None    None
1    n="1"   whose    id_1
2    n="2"  theirs    id_1
3    n="3"      am    id_1
4     None    None    None
5     id_2    None    None
6    n="4"      in    id_2
7    n="5"     out    id_2
8     None    None    None
9     id_3    None    None
10   n="6"      in    id_3
11   n="7"     out    id_3
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

For simplicity reasons I didn't use the exact format of my df (huge mistake, I apologise). The df starts with 3 supplementary rows and does not end with par. 

1st row: all columns are empty
2nd : column1 : <title>, column2 and column3: empty
3rd: all columns are empty

and ends with 

column1: </title></end>, column2 and column3: empty

Comment: Formatting is completely lost in comments so I don't understand what you mean. Would you mind updating your question to explain what the issue is?

Comment: I checked your code as if the dataframe started directly with the row id_1, and column 3 ended with par, and it works.

It was my fault that I didn't provide the right format from the beginning.
Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

You could do like that:

```
import numpy as np

df['Column3'] = np.where(df['Column3'].eq('par'),
                         df['Column1'].where(df['Column1'].str.contains('id')).ffill(),
                         np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3
0      id_1      NaN      NaN
1     n="1"    whose     id_1
2     n="2"   theirs     id_1
3     n="3"       am     id_1
4      id_2      NaN      NaN
5     n="4"       in     id_2
6     n="5"      out     id_2
7      id_3      NaN      NaN
8     n="6"       in     id_3
9     n="7"      out     id_3
```

Edit:

If there are also other values than 'par' in Column3, you can put df['Column3'] instead of np.nan at the end of the function. It's your decision if you wanna put 'nan' in that column for values other than 'par' or leave values which already exists there.